# how to extract the even number from user input, and combine them as a new number in C program

Tags: c

test case:

input: `1234`
output: `24`

input: `2468`
output: `2468`

input: `6`
output: `6`

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int numberLength = floor(log10(abs(num))) + 1;
    int inputNumberArray[numberLength];

    int evenNumberCount = 0;
    int even[10];//new even no. array

    int i = 0;
    do {
        inputNumberArray[i] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    } while (num != 0);

    i = 0;
    while (i < numberLength) {
        if (inputNumberArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenNumberCount ++;
            even[i] = inputNumberArray[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("array count %d\n", evenNumberCount);

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf(" %d", even[i]);//print even array
    }

    i = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (evenNumberCount == 1) {
            if (even[i] != 0) {
                result = even[i];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (even[i] != 0) {
                result = result + even[i] * pow(10, i);
            } else
                 break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nresult is %d", result);
    /*
    int a = 0;
    a = pow(10, 2);
    printf("\na is %d", a);
    */
}
```

when I enter number `1234`, the result/outcome is `4`, instead of `24`.

but when I test the rest of test case, it is fine.

the wrong code I think is this: `result = result + even[i] * pow(10, i);`

Can you help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

why do you have to read as number?
Simplest algorithm would be

- Read as text
- Validate
- loop through and confirm if divisible by 2 and print live

next thing, have you try to debug?
debug would let you know what are doing wrong. Finally the issue is with indexing.

```
evenNumberCount ++; /// this is technically in the wrong place. 
even[i]=inputNumberArray[i];  /// This is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the user Popeye suggested, an easier approach to accomplish this would be to just read in the entire input from the user as a string. With this approach, you can iterate through each letter in the char array and use the isdigit() method to see if the character is a digit or not. You can then easily check if that number is even or not.

Here is a quick source code I wrote up to show this approach in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char input[100] = { '\0' };
    char outputNum[100] = { '\0' };

    // Get input from user
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf_s("%s", input, sizeof(input));

    // Find the prime numbers
    int outputNumIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            if (input[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                outputNum[outputNumIndex++] = input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (outputNum[0] == '\0')
    {
        outputNum[0] = '0';
    }

    // Print the result
    printf("Result is %s", outputNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The character code of a digit is not necessarily even if the digit is even. It is just by chance that this is the case with ASCII or UTF-8.

Comment: @the busybee ... can you cite any current or historically-used character encoding where even-value digits do *not* have even-valued codepoints?  To save you checking, EBCDIC follows ASCII (and thus Unicode) in having this property.

Comment: @KrisW The first CCITT standards (starting with using 5-bit values), for example [documented here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070627151113/http://homepages.cwi.nl/~dik/english/codes/5tape.html#ccitt1), and [ITA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code#ITA_2_and_US-TTY) is still in [use today, see last paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code#ITA2). However, it is doubtful that there's a C compiler using this coding as source character set.

Comment: @KrisW But it doesn't matter, really. Since a character code digit is not the digit, I would see it as an error to check properties of a digit by evaluating those properties by the character code.

Comment: @KrisW Oops, concerning the character set: I ment the execution character set, not the source character set. And that could well be, if I think it over, since ITA-2 is still in use. Hm...

Comment: @the busybee To my knowledge (which is pretty detailed when it comes to text processing and early computing), no computer ever sold has ever used ITA-2 as an *internal* storage format - lots of reasons, but you could consider how important BCD was to early dataprocessing to see why.  Certainly, by 1971 when C was written, everything ran ASCII, EBCDIC or FIELDATA, all of which code their digits in a contiguous block, where even digits have even code values.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, which is easier to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define INIT_VALUE 999
int extEvenDigits1(int num);
void extEvenDigits2(int num, int *result);
int main()
{
 int number, result = INIT_VALUE;

 printf("Enter a number: \n");
 scanf("%d", &number);
 printf("extEvenDigits1(): %d\n", extEvenDigits1(number));
 extEvenDigits2(number, &result);
 printf("extEvenDigits2(): %d\n", result);
 return 0;
}
int extEvenDigits1(int num)
{

    int result = -1;
    int count = 0; 
    while (num > 1) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        if (digit % 2 == 0) {
            result = result == -1 ? digit : result + digit * pow(10, count);
            count++;
        }
        num = num / 10;
    }

    return result;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things, I'm afraid.

You could read the number *as a string* and easily process every character producing another string to be printed.

If you are required to deal with a numeric type, there is a simpler solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Keep asking for numbers until scanf fails.
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter a number:\n");

        // Using a bigger type, we can store numbers with more digits.
        long long int number;

        // Always check the value returned by scanf.
        int ret = scanf("%lld", &number);
        if (ret != 1)
            break;

        long long int result = 0;

        // Use a multiple of ten as the "position" of the resulting digit. 
        long long int power = 1;

        // The number is "consumed" while the result is formed.
        while (number)
        {
            // Check the last digit of what remains of the original number
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Put that digit in the correct position of the result
                result += (number % 10) * power;

                // No need to call pow()
                power *= 10;
            }

            // Remove the last digit.
            number /= 10;
        }

        printf("result is %lld\n\n", result);
    }
}
```